# Fatal error during compilation disable the site

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I tried to enable compilation and when I run the compilation process, I got this error. How can I solve this error?

> Fatal error: Class 'Alin_ProductGift_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup' not found in includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

Answer (score 3):

The error says,one of your external extension do not posses it's set up file. The module responsible for this is `Alin_ProductGift`. So Create a file like this.

File : `app/code/<codePool>/Alin/ProductGift/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php`

```
<?php
class Alin_ProductGift_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup 
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
}
```

That will resolve this issue

***Note*** : `codepool` may be `local` or `community` depends upon where `Alin_ProductGift` resides.